# How to get a next child div value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a value of a next child div. For more details, I click on a button but I want to get the value of the next child div. I’ve do this but I know it's not correct way to do.

```
 var nm = $(this '.fc-event-id').text();
```

This refer to the element clicked and `.fc-event-id` it's the class name that I would get it's text.Thanks for help!

Comment: can you post the html, where are you clicking & what you want to get?

Comment: can you show us your html markup as well? also a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com playground?

Comment: Try this: `var nm = $(this).next('div').text();`